# How to remember last used pages/Tabs in react Hooks?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am making a React app with 2 menu items Home and Find(two different urls). Home consists of sub tabs - a, b, c and Find consists of d, e, f. I am working on tab 'b' from Home and navigated to find page to look something, now when I click on the Home menu on the top, I am no longer in tab 'b'. How do I remember the previous path in react hooks any help or clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When navigating to another page-level component, the component will unmount, the state of the component will be clear from the memory by GC.

There are 3 options:

1. [Redux](https://redux.js.org/) - Put data in redux store, the data in redux store can be accessed by any component inside redux Provider.
2. [react context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) - CRUD the data in context, it's almost the same as redux.
3. [Lift state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) - Lift state up to parent component of these page-level components. Pass the state and the `setState` into these page-level components. E.g. The parent component is `App`, maintain the state for page-level components, it never unmounts except refresh the application so the state will always be there.
4. External storage - local storage, session storage, etc..
5. URL parameters - Put the selected tab in the URL parameter, when the user access the URL, get the selected tab from the URL parameter.

Answer (score 0):

If I need to return to a specific path after a page *refresh*, I use the following piece of code:

```
// after page refresh get last path
useEffect(() => {
    const lastPath = sessionStorage.getItem('pathname');

    if (lastPath) {
        return navigate(lastPath);
    }
}, []);

// update path value in sessionStorage
useUpdateEffect(() => {
    sessionStorage.setItem('pathname', pathname);
}, [pathname]);
```